# aggregateWindow summing incorrectly?

Tags: grafana, flux-influxdb

I have a dataset in influxdb with what looks like a relatively simple query.  The data only contains data from one day.  Snippet of the data below for the last rows of data points (there's no data points at all for 2023-09-20.

[Raw Data]
[image]

However when I use:

```
aggregateWindow(every: 1d, fn: sum)
```

[Incorrect sum - shows data for day where no data exists]
[image]

Having had this issue previously, I thought I'd actually solved it by using an offset to account for my timezone (UTC +8).  But now this still shows a sum value for day where there are no values.  i.e. using:

```
aggregateWindow(every: 1d, fn: sum, offset: 8h)
```

I still get a sum of data for 2023-09-20 even though the raw table before the aggregate has now data for that day.

[Incorrect sum with offset]
[image]